# How to handle message between server and client that has a length?

Tags: tcp, stream, packet

If a server is sending the length of message before sending the actual message e.g.:

```
   5ABCDE10FGHIJKLMNO
```

where '5' is length of message 'ABCDE' and '10' is length of message FGHIJKLMNO.

Could it arrive at client's end in any order in chucks of buffer depending on buffer size:

```
   5A BCD  E1  0FGHI  JKLMNO  
   5ABCD  E1  0F GHI  JKLMNO  
   5A BC D  E1  0F GHI  JKLM NO  
   ... so on
```

i.e. when you read from socket, say, you get '5A' and on second read you get 'BCD'. Is this a possibility?

If so, do I need to manually handle the cases and possibilities about how the data will arrive i.e. whether length is there, message is complete etc. to put together the message?

Comment: You could try using a set of characters, that when received, instructs the client that the message is about to start / finish. Like html tags.

Comment: The answer to both questions is: `yes`.

Comment: Thanks, Is there a C++ or Java library to handle this?

Comment: Depends on the actual message format. A real library would not expect the length header to be in ASCII characters, for example. Anyway, it's a nice exercise to program this from scratch.